# Populated checkbox columns in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, checkbox

I have 8 columns populated as checkboxes in a gridview. I need to know how to get the values from them and store them in a database using C#. Kindly help.

aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="etable" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rollnumber" HeaderText="Roll Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="IBM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkibm" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="FOL">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkfol" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="IS">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkis" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="CP">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkcp" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="WIM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkwim" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="STTPO">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chksttpo" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="TDM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chktdm" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="PA">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkpa" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="ID Card">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkid" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `CheckBox` Field is in `database` use this

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IBM" HeaderText="IBM"/>
```

instead of

```
 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="IBM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkibm" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```